# how to clone a Vector in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I need a clean copy of a Vector not a reference.

In Swing I use Vector.clone(); (Not Allowed in codenmeone complains its protected.)

In Codenameone I tried **Vector someName** = new Vector(**(Vector)anotherVector**)

**someName** becomes a referance as what ever changes are made to **anotherVector**, **someName**  inherits those changes.

Thoughts?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

The new vector approach works but it isn't a deep copy of the elements within. Unfortunately you can't do a deep copy since `clone()` requires reflection which we don't have. Unfortunately there's no easy answer. You would need to literally go over every element and create a copy of that element since we can't generically duplicate it.

This can be relatively simple, assuming a vector of `MyObject` which has a constructor that accepts an existing instance then something like this will work:

```
Vector<MyObject> newVector = new Vector<>();
for(MyObject obj : oldVector) {
    newVector.add(new MyObject(obj));
}
```